# how i can change place of ElevatedButton

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          leading: const Icon(Icons.home),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
          title: const Text('test app'),
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(

            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'New',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        fontSize: 40,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        height: 2,
                        shadows: [
                          Shadow(color: Colors.black12, offset: Offset(4, 10))
                        ]),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton.icon(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),label: Text(' '),
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey),
                      
                    ),
                  ),


                ],
              ),
              Row(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Please describe where you want to move it, and give more information about your issue, we are glad to help you.

Comment: Use Stack instead of Row

Comment: See this layout tutorial in the flutter docs, it will help to build your layouts as you want: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/tutorial

Comment: Don't bypass the system by pasting code-text. You need to describe the issue, what you have tried so far and what are you being trying to archive. It is not clear what are you trying to archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the Row widget properties for laying out its childrens

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: [....]
 )
```

the official docs are helpful in that matter
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html

- sidenote: if you are not planning to use any of the first container() properties then its better to get rid of it

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 options u can use depending on what you want

1. If u want it below new u can use Column instead of Row .
2. If u want to put some space next to new u can use SizedBox(width:X) between the Text and the elevated button.
3. You can use mainAxisAlignment or crossAxisAlignment inside the row or column to customize the position
   you can find examples about them here https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout
4. you can use margin or padding on elevated button to customize its own position